# Can I control the music player on my iPhone from a PC?

Tags: iphone, ipod, usb

Is there any app (or otherwise) that allows me to select audio tracks to play, or even just skip to the next track on my iPhone 4 via a PC connected to the iPhone by USB?

Comment: Not directly an answer, but AirFoil allows you to steam audio from your computer an iPhone or other iOS device. http://rogueamoeba.com/ Regarding the real question, the best I can think of would be something that can operate as an AVRCP controller, but I have not been able to find a Windows app to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bowtie should solve your problem. It's a free desktop app that talks to a .99 cent app that you download on the iPhone:

[Bowtie](http://bowtieapp.com/)